# How to correctly add adapter from two references in Kotlin Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to make something like a quiz. After completing a test, results are being saved in [this tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpl3A.png) by current users' UID. Then a user can open the educational course progress and watch a score number on every completed part of this course(plus they can click on the part and go right to it). I tryed to make it this way

```
private fun listenForProgress() {
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/course/$courseUid/parts/")

    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            p0.children.forEach {
                val coursePart = it.getValue(PartOfCourse::class.java)!!
                coursePartUid = coursePart.uid

                val saveScoreRef =  instance
                    .getReference("/course/$courseUid/parts/$coursePartUid/score/$currentUserUid")

               saveScoreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
                   override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                       p0.children.forEach {
                           val courseProgress = it.getValue(ScoreItem::class.java)
                           adapter.add(ProgressLeft(courseProgress!!))
                       }
                   }

                   override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }
               })
            }

            adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->

                val partOfCourseItem = item as PartOfCourseItem
                val intent = Intent(view.context, InfoActivity::class.java)
                coursePartUid = partOfCourseItem.partOfCourse.uid
                coursePartTitle = partOfCourseItem.partOfCourse.title
                intent.putExtra("courseUid", courseUid)
                intent.putExtra("coursePartUid", coursePartUid)
                intent.putExtra("coursePartTitle", coursePartTitle)
                startActivity(intent)

                finish()
            }

            progressRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

The first reference works just great, but I have a problem with the second one by getting this kind of exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.awesomeproject, PID: 6085
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.awesomeproject.models.ScoreItem
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:435)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:203)
        at com.example.awesomeproject.courses.ProgressActivity$listenForProgress$1$onDataChange$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.onDataChange(ProgressActivity.kt:67)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I'm saving data with

```
@Parcelize
class ScoreItem(
    val userUid: String,
    val coursePartUid: String,
    val score: Int,
    val partTitle: String
): Parcelable {
    constructor(): this("", "", 0, "")
}
```

and trying to get it with

```
 class ProgressLeft(
    val progress: ScoreItem
): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.progress_left_row_layout
    }

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.scoreTextView.text = progress.score.toString()
        viewHolder.itemView.partTitleTextView.text = progress.partTitle
    }
}
```

it is a part of JSON file, where I'm working now

```
 "course" : {
      "b2611197-1b36-4908-89c2-9dd067fa66e3" : {
      "description" : "Dogs are cute",
      "imageCourseUrl" : "https://sun9-66.userapi.com/c851028/v851028425/a6e1a/gadTK-MxieA.jpg",
      "parts" : {
        "95706cfa-2c4c-4e39-b433-8e13c7212a2d" : {
          "imageUrl" : "https://sun9-45.userapi.com/c635100/v635100806/62080/mrLF0IyBzNA.jpg",
          "info" : "James Franko has four puppies",
          "score" : {
            "Vk6IOCAaFMdwdruZrrb9DhmDdDh2" : {
              "coursePartUid" : "95706cfa-2c4c-4e39-b433-8e13c7212a2d",
              "partTitle" : "First part",
              "score" : 2,
              "userUid" : "Vk6IOCAaFMdwdruZrrb9DhmDdDh2"
            }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include: 1) the complete stack trace for the error message, 2) the JSON that is being loaded when the error occurs (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I've added it; maybe now you can help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your nested listener only loads the score for a single player, so it shouldn't be looping over the child nodes in `onDataChange`. By doing that, your `it` becomes an individual property, and trying to read a `from a single property value is leading to the` message you get.

It more likely should look something like this:

```
val saveScoreRef =  instance.getReference("/course/$courseUid/parts/$coursePartUid/score/$currentUserUid")

saveScoreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
   override fun onDataChange(scoreSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
       val courseProgress = scoreSnapshot.getValue(ScoreItem::class.java)
       adapter.add(ProgressLeft(courseProgress!!))
   }

   override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
       throw error.toException();
   }
```

A few more notes on the above:

- Please never leave `onCancelled` empty, as you may be hiding important problems that way.
- When you attach the outer listener to `/course/$courseUid/parts/`, its `onDataChange` gets called with **all** data under that location. So you shouldn't need a nested listener, but can instead get all data from the original `p0`  (I highly recommend giving parameters more meaningful names than these defaults, as I've done above with `scoreSnapshot).